# Running R-script with parameters via system() from within another R script

Tags: r, cmd, rscript

I have a process in R that monitors a website (lets call it A). Once an event happens, I want to start up another R-script with it's own process (lets call it B). The initial R script (A) needs to pass parameters into the second script (B). The initial script needs to keep going monitoring... It might find another event and will need to start another instance of B. it is possible to have up to 10ish B-scripts running at any point in time.

When I open a CMD window and run this, it works:

```
Rscript.exe C:/Temp/myBscript.R parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4
```

but, when I run the following code in R, it does not work:

```
  system(
        paste("Rscript.exe C:/Temp/myBscript.R", parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4)
        , wait=FALSE)
```

The `wait = TRUE` is there so I can start multiple B scripts and A does not wait for B to finish.

In addition, I have other scripts that I would like to run from a location with spaces in the folder name. I've tried things like:

```
system(
       paste("\"Rscript.exe \"C:\\My Drive\\Folder with spaces in Name\\My B script with spaces.R\"", parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4 "\"\"") 
       , wait=FALSE)
```

but with no success...

EDIT: The Rstudio console just returns '0'. I know its not working, because script-B should write a file... which it does not when I run the commands above in R (but does write a file when I run the first option [directly in CMD]). Also, in Windows Task Manager I see it does not start a 'CMD task'

EDIT2:

Example script A:

```
parameter1 = "testPara1"
parameter2 = "InfoPart2"
system(
  paste("Rscript.exe C:/Temp/myBscript.R", parameter1, parameter2)
  , wait=FALSE)
```

Example script B (C:/Temp/myBscript.R):

```
args  = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
par1  = args[1]
par2  = args[2]

dd <- data.frame("parameter1" = par1,
                 "parameter2" = par2)

write.csv(dd, "C:\\Temp\\TestFileWithParameters.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Have you considered running background jobs in RStudio?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? Is there an error?

Comment: @RobertHacken I have added more info to the post in the EDIT section.

Comment: @Friede Possibly interesting indeed! I'll have to explore. I see a lot of discussion re passing parameters... But the fact they are separate instances is interesting. I'll see if i can make a POC.

Comment: @Luc `0` is good, that means no error and the script should actually be running. Maybe it is saving its output somewhere you don't expect it, did you set the correct working directory in R?

Comment: @RobertHacken I never use 'working directories', I always point to where I want it to be saved... I can't see evidence of it working...

Comment: @Luc What does `getwd()` return in R? I don't know what your script does but is its output possibly in that directory?

Comment: @RobertHacken There are no files written in the working directory. Confirmed.

Comment: @Luc Ok, then I'm afraid it is difficult to tell what is going on without more information such as what's inside the script.

Comment: @RobertHacken I have added an example that demonstrates my issue. Running the system() command in A does not run B, but when I paste the result of the paste0 part in a CMD window, it does run.

Comment: @Friede Do you know if a background job can start another background job? I wasnt able to find this using google. In my case, Script B will start script C in some cases (I didnt mention that in my post, perhaps I should have!).

Comment: Strange, it works just fine for me. When I run `Rscript.exe C:/Temp/myAscript.R` in R, `myAscript.R` runs, the `system` command inside it runs `myBscript.R` and the CSV file is saved as expected.

Comment: I meant when I run `system('Rscript.exe C:/Temp/myAscript.R')` in R..

Comment: @RobertHacken this might be a case of 'did you restart?'... its working.... gee how frustrating!

Comment: @RobertHacken do you know what the code would look like when there are spaces in the folder structure?

Comment: Glad it works! To deal with spaces in the folder structure you need to enclose paths in your `system` calls in double quotes. If you use single quotes for the whole string, you won't need any backslashes for this, e.g.: `system('Rscript.exe "C:/dir with spaces/script.R"')`. `write.csv` doesn't seem to need any special treatment so e.g. `write.csv(dd, 'C:/dir with spaces/output.csv')` should work just fine.